# Register Nib/Class cell crash on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8.3

I have used the following code in `viewDidLoad` to register nib cell :

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ShoppingViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ShoppingViewCell")
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I use the following for cell:

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShoppingViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ShoppingViewCell

return cell
```

But Sadly this only works with IOS 9 and up, trying to run this code on iOS 8.3 crashes with following error :

```
2016-09-27 14:17:04.859 Tazaj[29070:1917376] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:6245
2016-09-27 14:17:04.877 Tazaj[29070:1917376] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ShoppingViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Since register nib and dequeueReusableCell is already found since iOS 5/6, why its not working on iOS 8.3.

I know that by running the following code in `cellForRowAtIndex` will solve the issue :

```
    var mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShoppingViewCell") as? ShoppingViewCell

    if (mycell == nil) {

        mycell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ShoppingViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)?.last as? ShoppingViewCell

    }
```

But I have builded a whole project without check that cell is nil or not. I mean how can I solve the issue ? since apple said register cell and use the cell the way you want, I did it. so why only in iOS 8.x/8.3 it cannot work ?

How is it possible to ignore/fix that error with least replacing chunks of code in each `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put this method in your custom cell class

```
class func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ShoppingViewCell {
    let kShoppingViewCellIdentifier = "kShoppingViewCellIdentifier"
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ShoppingViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: kShoppingViewCellIdentifier)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kShoppingViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ShoppingViewCell
    return cell
}
```

And use it lieke below in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let cell = ShoppingViewCell.cellForTableView(tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)
// do something with your cell
```

I hope it helps.

**Update for Swift 3 and Swift 4**

```
class func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> YourCustomTableViewCell {
    let kYourCustomTableViewCellIdentifier = "kYourCustomTableViewCellIdentifier"
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourCustomTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: kYourCustomTableViewCellIdentifier)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kYourCustomTableViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourCustomTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```